# How do you view email messages sent to greenmail

Tags: greenmail

I have an application that uses camel to send email. There is a greenmail server set up in our environment. The testers testing the service need to be able to view the emails sent, to verify that the html is formatted correctly.
There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to point a browser at the greenmail server to view the email.
Note that we use wildfly, and JMX with wildfly and dockers is not reliable. Is there something besides jmx?

Answer (score 4):

Use Thunderbird client. Set it up so that it uses pop3 and your server/port that hosts your greenmail.

You can create a separate user and specify it in CC for your mail so that the observation of the mail would not impact the core process you test.

Here is more detailed post on [how to setup Thunderbird with Greenmail](https://webelement.click/en/greenmail_setup_mock_to_test_emailing_with_greenmail).